# Configuración de 2amigos/usuario Yii2

Tags: yii2

estoy tratando de configurar la extensión 2amigos/usuario en YII2 basic, lo eh configurado de acuerdo a su manual. Siguiendo las instrucciones paso a paso utilice el método dos para configurar, agregando código de acuerdo al manual en el archivo config/web.php y config/console.php, agregue el primer usuario administrador usando la migración de ejemplo en el manual de la extensión. 
Todo bien, sin problemas inicio sesión y demás pero el problema es con los permisos, el usuario esta como administrador, revise la base de datos y pertenece al grupo de usuario administrator.
Cuando ingreso a la ruta: /user/admin/index, veo el siguiente mensaje

You are not allowed to perform this action.

Seguramente no lo eh configurado correctamente, pero ya mire el manual nuevamente y no veo que mas se pueda hacer para gestionar los permisos.

Answer (score 0):

de nuevo a quien vio la pregunta, jejeje. Eh encontrado la respuesta, por si a alguien le sirve fue en la modificación del código en el archivo: vendor\2amigos\yii2-usuario\src\User\Controller\AbstractAuthItemController.php
El código modificado fue:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                'ruleConfig' => [
                    'class' => AccessRuleFilter::class,
                ],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['administrator'], //cambie de admin a administrator que es el nombre del Rol de os administradores.
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Detalles de ser nuevo en el framework,
Saludos.

Comment: No se por que los saludos, al inicio no aparecen, me hace ver como una persona algo mal educada.